# VS2013 line numbers not evenly spaced

Tags: visual-studio-2013

This is the minorest of annoyances, but nevertheless it's still an annoyance.  One day my line numbers in Visual Studio 2013 suddenly stopped being evenly spaced...

[image]

The lines of codes themselves are fine, just the line numbers are weird.  I'm guessing it's something to do with Productivity Power Tools, but for the life of me I can't find any setting that fixes it.  I don't really have any other extensions installed that would affect something like that.  Anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Productivity Power Tools 2013 has an option to compress white space to allow more code to fit on the screen.

---

**Description**

The description on the [Productivity Power Tools 2013](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace) page says:

> **Syntactic Line Compression**
>
> Syntactic line compression enables you to make better use of your screen's vertical real-estate. It shrinks lines that contain neither letters nor numbers by 25% vertically, allowing more lines to be displayed in the editor. Other lines are not affected.
>
> [image: from MSDN]

---

**Disabling the setting**

You can turn this off if it bothers you by going to

```
Tools/Options/Productivity Power Tools/Turn Extensions On/Off
```

[image: compress]

but I find it does help readability with larger files.

Comment: And now that I know what the cause is, I think you're right and I'll leave it enabled.  I never even noticed it was shrinking the size of the curly braces and blank lines, but when I disabled it the difference was noticeable.

Comment: @Malleus - no problem - it's the kind of thing that gets really annoying when you don't know *why* it's happening. I noticed it myself a while ago when I installed the extension then did some digging and found the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think this actually comes from C# formatting. These is an option to always show braces `{` and `}` on single lines and have those lines be smaller.